# with javascript function created select onchange with counter parameter

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function which creates a div with 2 selects. In this function I use a counter to keep track of the count of the divs. At the end of the function I increase this counter. I want to give the value of the not yet increased counter as a parameter of an onchange function beceuase I added that counter at the end of the select id. But when I change the select value it uses the new counter value.

```
var counter = 1;
function addLine(itemId){

                var specificationsDiv = document.getElementById('specificationsAdding' + itemId);
                var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
                newDiv.innerHTML = "<div><select id='specificationNames"+ Counter +"' onchange='changeSpecificationSelects(counter)'><option>a</option><option>b</option></select><select id='specificationValues"+ Counter +"'><option>a</option><option>b</option></select></div>";
                specificationsDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
                counter++;
}
```

So when I use a button to call this function and I change the select it uses 2 as parameter for the onchange so I do not get the right id of the select. How do I give the old value of this counter as a parameter for the onchange?

I can not use this.id beceause in the onchange of the first select I need to get the id of the first select and the second select I created.

Comment: You are sending new value of counter because your onchange function will be executed AFTER counter is increased. When div with select element is shown on the page, that means your function addLine is already finished and counter is increased.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I change the code to use the value before the counter is increased?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a stab at this without 100% understanding the actual reasons. Maybe someone better at JS can chip in too.

### Explanation

Something about the way you pass counter to the onchange function.
Everywhere else, you pass is out of quotes:

```
"... id='specificationNames"+ counter +"' ..."
```

But in your onchange function you leave it in the string:

```
"... onchange='changeSpecificationSelects(counter)' ..."
```

This seems to "bind" your counter variable at runtime.

### Solution

**JavaScript primitive types are copied by value**. So, do it like the other places take it out of quotes and pass it as a variable:

```
"... onchange='changeSpecificationSelects("+ counter +")' ..."
```

Also remember to watch you cases. **C**ounter vs **c**ounter.

Not related, but since you're a new contributor, take a look at jQuery

```
document.getElementById(...) becomes $("...")
```

Comment: using onchange='changeSpecificationSelects("+ counter +") instead of onchange='changeSpecificationSelects(counter) fixed it. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

You could continue down the route you are going. Instead of dynamically generating a string of JS containing a reference to a global variable, you could generate one with a number literal.

… but don't do this. It will make the code even harder to maintain.

Instead, generate your DOM by using standard DOM methods (instead of building a string of HTML and then converting it to a DOM with `innerHTML`). Add the event listener with `addEventListener` and use a closure to capture the current value.

```js
var counter = 1;

function addLine(itemId) {

  var specificationsDiv = document.getElementById('specificationsAdding' + itemId);
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  var select = document.createElement("select");
  ['a', 'b', 'c'].forEach(function(letter) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(letter));
    select.appendChild(option);
  });
  select.addEventListener("change", changeSpecificationSelectsFactory(counter));
  newDiv.appendChild(select);
  specificationsDiv.appendChild(newDiv);

  counter++;
}

function changeSpecificationSelectsFactory(value) {
  function changeSpecificationSelects() {
    alert(value);
  }
  return changeSpecificationSelects;
}

addLine(1);
addLine(1);
addLine(1);
```

```html
<div id="specificationsAdding1"></div>
```